# how to check if the user is a normal user or an admin user PHP

Tags: php, database, forms

I can log in to the website with the normal user and the admin user,
I would like to check if the user is a normal user or an admin user and then send them to a different page but it doesnt work when I tried the following i was unable to log in with any credentials.

I modify my db table to add a column for userType, 2 if it is an admin and 1 if it is a normal user

this is what a tried:

```
   if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 2)
{
   //do stuff here 
}
 if ($_SESSION['usertype'] == 1)

 {
 //do stuff here 
 }
```

This is my php file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.php';
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE utepEmail=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: index.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mail);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['Password']);
            if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                exit();
            } elseif ($pwdCheck == true) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['Name'];
                header("Location: index.php?success");
                exit();
            } else {
                eader("Location: index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: login.php?error=noouser");
            exit();
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You are only setting `$_SESSION['username']`. You need to set `$_SESSION['usertype']` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main PHP file, you probably need to set the session variable for the user type, so that when you later use that type, the value has been set.
The right place to do this is when the password is checked.

```
...
elseif ($pwdCheck == true) {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['username'] = $row['Name'];
   $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype']; // <- add user type to the session
   header("Location: index.php?success");
   exit();
}
...
```

When the 'success' page is loaded, it will pick up the usertype and your structure could then work.